# Wix toolset - MSI uninstall fails if IIS has been uninstalled

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, wix3.11

I've created an installer with Wix Toolset 3.11 that installes a web site in IIS using Wixs IISExtension.

I install the MSI and everything looks good so far.
Now I uninstall the IIS role while the MSI is still installed. (did this for testing purposes)
Problem: The MSI now cannot be uninstalled anymore. The uninstallation fails, as it cannot make changes to the IIS config anymore. It's throwing errors in the uninstall.log regarding this, performes a rollback of uninstall and leaves the application installed.

In my opinion this should be a corner case, but does anybody know some kind of switch or workaround to ignore these errors and continue with the uninstallation? Any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is a scenario that is well known so I'm surprised your getting this.  It Condition (LaunchCondition) elements we always say...

SOMETHINGTHATISREQUIRED and Not Installed

...so that the REQUIRED is evaluated during initial installation but not subsequent transactions including uninstall.  Looking at built MSI the custom action condition is

NOT SKIPCONFIGUREIIS AND VersionNT > 400

I'd think a condition could be made that verified IIS was still present or maybe the custom action code could do a try/catch best effort.  Maybe the decision was made to not do that because it could leave traces behind and result in a dirty uninstall.

So you can document  msiexec /x yourproduct SKIPCONFIGUREIIS=1  and you'll be able to uninstall.

You could open an issue with WiX. My guess is they will answer it's by design.